# Publishing an application in an old version of .NET

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, compilation

I've written a really simple launcher app for my team at work to use.  However I wrote it in VB.net Express 2010 so its using .NET 4.  I need it to be compatible with older machines that are using .NET 2 or maybe 2.5.

I don't want to force upgrading to a higher .net if its not needed.  And in some cases we work on old machines that can't be upgraded.  My app is really simple and I'll post the code if needed.

Please note, I am still a noob, my coding is ugly, and this is a quick and dirty tool.

Comment: .Net 2.5 does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the Target Framework dropdown in Project Properties.

Comment: found it, its buried in vbexpress 2010 under properties->compile->advanced compile options->target.  Thanks!